# How to install and run a window manager on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager

I am a noob in configuring and understand unix architecture so please bare with me. I want to install Ubuntu Server on my laptop for learning purposes. Just want to add a simple window manager like spectrwm but so far I haven't been able to get any info on how to run it.

What I did so far:
1. install Ubuntu 20.04 server
2. install xinit (which should be the display manager)
3. install spectrwm - the actual window manager

However, I can't find how to run the window manager.

NOTE: i don't want to install a desktop enviroment, i'm not interrested in that

EDIT:
I found [a wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox) on how to run openbox but i can't find anywhere how to run spectrwm. If i do "sudo spectrwm" i just get

> spectrwm: Cannot open display

Comment: Why don't you install the desktop Ubuntu? Anything that runs on the server edition also runs on the desktop one. And the server edition may not have all the device drivers for you laptop (wifi and video...).

Comment: @xenoid i want to understand how the unix architecture work and i want to tinker around

Comment: Window managers are generally run as a normal user. It is typically discouraged to run window managers or Xorg with sudo or as root.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a plethora of times over at [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

There's even official documentation on the topic [located here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI)

Here's an answer in [Askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments#162518)